# How to include iframes in springy.js code?

Tags: javascript, iframe, springy.js

I am trying to add iframes as nodes in springy.js. While I understand some code, I do not understand what part of springyui.js to modify so as to include iframes as nodes.

I am able to render images as nodes using [this](http://bl.ocks.org/tdhsmith/42080337c9a7bcc6b40a), but not iframes. Any pointers would help.

Thanks in advance